# Fill an array with random numbers while obeying designated sum, count, and number boundaries

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have to fill an array with random numbers to satisfy a few conditions:

1. The number of elements in the result array must match the designated number.
2. The sum of the numbers in the result array must equal the designated number.
3. Random numbers must be selected between designated lower and upper bounds.

For example:

- Sum of the array: 130
- Total array elements: 3
- Random integers' lower bound: 23
- Random integers' upper bound: 70

Possible result:

```
array(23, 70, 37)
```

What to do now? How to split/divide my number?

I started with this (pseudo code):

```
i=0;
while(sum(number) > 0 and i < arraykeys){
    x = randomize(from, to)
    number = number - x
    myarray[i] = x
    i++
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

#### Code explanation

1. **Workability**

   The first thing we need to check is, if it is possible to build the goal out of numbers from the scope:

   ```
   if(checkWorkability($result, $goal, $amountOfElementsLeft, $scope))
   ```

   Means it just uses the highest values possible and looks if it is bigger than the goal.
2. **While loop**

   In the while loop we need to check if we still have elements left which we can use:

   ```
   while($amountOfElementsLeft > 0)
   ```
3. **Scope adjustment**

   Every iteration we need to check if we need to adjust the scope, so that at the end we will be able to build the goal.

   This means if the current sum of numbers + the highest possible number is bigger than the goal, we need to make the max value of the scope smaller.

   Also on the opposite side we need to make the min value of the scope bigger, when we can't reach our goal anymore.

#### Code

```
<?php


    $goal = 130;
    $amountOfElementsLeft = 3;
    $scope = [23, 70];

    $result= [];


    function adjustScope(array $result, $goal, $amountOfElementsLeft, $scope) {

        $newScope = $scope;

        if($amountOfElementsLeft == 1) {
            $leftOver = $goal - array_sum($result);
            return [$leftOver, $leftOver];
        }


        if((($goal - (array_sum($result) + $scope[1])) / ($amountOfElementsLeft - 1)) < $scope[0])
            $newScope[1] = (int) ($goal - array_sum($result)) / ($scope[0] * ($amountOfElementsLeft - 1));
        elseif(($adjustTop = $goal - array_sum($result)) < $scope[1])
            $newScope[1] = $adjustTop;

        if(($adjustBottom = $goal - (array_sum($result) + $scope[0] + (($amountOfElementsLeft - 1) * $scope[1]))) < $goal && $adjustBottom > 0)
            $newScope[0] = $scope[0] + $adjustBottom;

        return $newScope;

    }

    function checkWorkability(array $result, $goal, $amountOfElementsLeft, $scope) {
        if(array_sum($result) + $amountOfElementsLeft * $scope[1] >= $goal)
            return TRUE;
        return FALSE;
    }


    if(checkWorkability($result, $goal, $amountOfElementsLeft, $scope)) {
        while($amountOfElementsLeft > 0) {
            $scope = adjustScope($result, $goal, $amountOfElementsLeft, $scope);

            $result[] = rand($scope[0], $scope[1]);
            $amountOfElementsLeft--;

        }
    }

    print_r($result);
    echo array_sum($result);

?>
```

possible outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 58
    [1] => 30
    [2] => 42
) -> 130
Array
(
    [0] => 35
    [1] => 54
    [2] => 41
) -> 130
Array
(
    [0] => 52
    [1] => 51
    [2] => 27
) -> 130
```

Comment: Very good work, by doesn't work for numbers
`$goal = 114;
$amountsleft = 51;
$scope=[1,5]`

Comment: @user2184072 Forgot that, it doesn't check if the number is low enough, so you get all elements filled.

Comment: @user2184072 Should be a bit better now. Updated the code. (Still has 1 bug in it, but I will correct it soon)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a custom function for portability and to meaningfully implement some guard conditions which throw exceptions when incoming parameters make the desired result impossible.

1. Loop one less than `$count` times -- this is because the final element in the returned array is determined by the difference between the desired total and the sum of the randomly acquired values.
2. Adjust the lower and upper bounds of the `$scope` array (if required) to ensure a successfully populated return array.
3. Get a random integer, push it into the return array, then subtract it from the `$total`.
4. When the looped processes are finished, push the remaining `$total` value as the final element in the return array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YEo8s))

```
function getRandWithStipulations(int $total, int $count, array $scope): array
{
    if ($scope[0] > $scope[1]) {
        throw new Exception('Argument 3 (\$scope) is expected to contain a minimum integer then a maximum integer.');
    }
    if ($scope[0] * $count > $total) {
        throw new Exception('Arguments 2 (\$count) and 3 (\$scope) can only exceed argument 1 (\$total).');
    }
    if ($scope[1] * $count < $total) {
        throw new Exception('Arguments 2 (\$count) and 3 (\$scope) cannot reach argument 1 (\$total).');
    }
    $result = [];
    for ($x = 1; $x < $count; ++$x) { // count - 1 iterations
        $scope[0] = max($scope[0], $total - ($scope[1] * ($count - $x)));
        $scope[1] = min($scope[1], $total - ($scope[0] * ($count - $x)));
        $rand = rand(...$scope);
        $result[] = $rand;
        $total -= $rand;
    }
    $result[] = $total;
    return $result;
}
try {
    var_export(
        getRandWithStipulations(
            130,
            3,
            [23, 70]
        )
    );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage();
}
```

A few random results:

- `[60, 34, 36]`
- `[23, 59, 48]`
- `[67, 36, 27]`
- `[47, 23, 60]`